# Moving thumb through a trail with snapping

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, dom-events

First, interact the example below.

This component must work exactly like an input type range.
The problem I'm having is calculate the step value, *and* snap the thumb into the trail based on the proportion of the current step and the max value (*again, exactly like a range input*).

Any responses that uses a native range input to control this behaviour is welcome. I haven't used it only because of the snap which is not smooth.

```js
const thumb = document.querySelector(".stepper__step");
const trail = document.querySelector(".stepper__trail");

// Variables that controls the range snap and values
var minVal = 0;
var maxVal = 20;
var step = 2;

thumb.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

thumb.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  addGrabbingClassFromThumb();

  let shiftX = event.clientX - thumb.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  // shiftY not needed, the thumb moves only horizontally

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    let newLeft = event.clientX - shiftX - trail.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    // the pointer is out of trail => lock the thumb within the bounaries
    if (newLeft < 0) {
      newLeft = 0;
    }
    let rightEdge = trail.offsetWidth - thumb.offsetWidth;
    if (newLeft > rightEdge) {
      newLeft = rightEdge;
    }

    thumb.style.left = newLeft + "px";
  }

  function onMouseUp() {
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  }
});

thumb.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  removeGrabbingClassFromThumb();
});

function addGrabbingClassFromThumb() {
  thumb.className += " stepper__step--grabbing";
}

function removeGrabbingClassFromThumb() {
  thumb.className = thumb.className.replace(/stepper__step--grabbing/g, "");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.stepper-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.stepper__trail {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.stepper__step {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.stepper__step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.stepper__step--grabbing {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
  transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-wrapper">
  <div class="stepper__step"></div>
  <div class="stepper__trail"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a [codesandbox](https://codesanbox.io) that illustrates this functionality?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/269j14Ln/

Comment: [Here's a quick attempt from me](https://jsfiddle.net/g5jxzqLw/). There is some more math that needs to be done in order to finesse out the possible range points and to ensure that the boundaries are better respected. I hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome! Solved my problem. I was struggling to make this work. Please, make it an answer so that I can vote as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing a few calculations and helper functions to determine *how* to snap.

First, we need the wrapper:

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.stepper-wrapper');
```

Next, we need to calculate a few values to use to generate our range points:

```
const containerWidth = wrapper.offsetWidth
const pixelsPerStep = Math.round(containerWidth / maxVal)
const totalSteps = Math.round(pixelsPerStep / step);
```

A quick couple helper functions to generate our range and find our closest possible point to snap to:

```
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) =>
  Array(Math.ceil((stop - start) / step)).fill(start).map((x, y) => x + y * step)

const closest = (range, goal) => {
  return range.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev)
  })
}
```

And in our `mousedown` event listener, we can generate the point we can snap through:

```
const snapTo = closest(rangePoints, newLeft);
```

This can be used as the `.left` property of the `thumb` element.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5jxzqLw/) for illustration.